# How can you specify ./configure args with rpmbuild?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I'm trying to build an rpm with nginx, and the nginx rtmp module.

I got my nginx source tar.gz, and my rtmp tar.gz, and placed them in the SOURCES dir.

I then made this spec file:

```
Name:       nginx
Version:    1.16.1
Release:    1%{?dist}
Summary:    Nginx with RTMP module

License:    GPLv3 Probably
URL:        nginx.com
Source0:    nginx-1.16.1.tar.gz
Source1:    nginx-rtmp-module.tar.gz


BuildRequires:  openssl-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel gd-devel perl-ExtUtils-Embed geoip-devel gperftools-devel pcre-devel zlib-devel
Requires: bash glibc glibc glibc openssl-libs openssl-libs openssl-libs glibc glibc pcre gperftools-libs glibc glibc openssl-libs openssl-libs zlib nginx-all-modules nginx-filesystem nginx-filesystem openssl pcre pcre centos-indexhtml glibc glibc centos-logos systemd 

%description
Nginx 1.16.1 with RTMP module

%prep
%setup -q
%setup -q -T -D -a 1


%build
%configure --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E' --add-module=./nginx-rtmp-module
make 


%install
make install
```

This is my first attempt at making an RPM with rpmbuild, or creating a specfile.
The 2 packages appear to be extracted to the BUILD dir properly, but the output of `rpmbuild -ba SPECS/nginx-with-rtmp.spec` shows this error:

> ./configure **--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/var/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info** --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-ipv6 --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_degradation_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_perl_module=dynamic --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-pcre-jit --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_ssl_module --with-google_perftools_module --with-debug '--with-cc-opt=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic' '--with-ld-opt=-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E' --add-module=./nginx-rtmp-module
>
> ./configure: error: invalid option "--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"
>
> error: Bad exit status from
>   /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.h4kaTW (%build)

rpmbuild appears to be adding args to `./configure` that I didn't ask for (everything in bold), which are breaking the build. It's also overriding some of my args, like `prefix`.

How can I tell rpmbuild to stop adding args to `./configure`? My build works fine when I run that `./configure` command manually without rpmbuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don’t want (or need) the standard arguments provided by the `%configure` macro, you don’t need to use it:

```
%build
./configure ...
make
```

(`./` instead of `%`.)

You should still use [the appropriate macros](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/RPMMacros/#_macros_for_paths_set_and_used_by_build_systems) for path components in the `./configure` arguments.

Comment: Holy crap - it worked! I could have sworn I tried that multiple times. Maybe something got cached somewhere, so when I tried `./configure` after having already used `%configure`, it was using cache or something. It works on a fresh system. Thanks!